# How to assert that a binding's value is undefined in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to verify that on page load, a certain `ng-model` is undefined.  However, the `div` that defines the `ng-model` is using an `ng-if` statement that evaluates to false for this test, and it seems like protractor cannot find any element with the given binding.  Is there a way to check for my models value without changing the view's code?

Currently, my test is:

```
describe('loading the create invoice page for the first time', function() {

    it('should have an undefined invoice.messages value', function() {

        browser.get('http://persianturtle.com/app/#/invoice/create');

        expect(element(by.binding('invoice.messages'))).toBe(undefined);

    });
});
```

And the result of the test:

`NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.binding("invoice.messages")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isPresent()`:

```
expect(element(by.binding('invoice.messages')).isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
```

[Here is the Protractor documentation](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent) for `isPresent()`.

However, you may have to pick a DOM `id` or `css` instead of `binding`:

```
expect(element(by.id('#id-in-the-dom-for-invoice-messages')).isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
expect(element(by.css('.class-in-the-dom-for-invoice-messages')).isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
```